# disable submit button if there is validation errors in form inputs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to disable submit button if there is a validation error from form inputs using jquery. The following is code that I am using:
HTML:

```
<form action="/order" id="orderForm" class="orderform" autocomplete="off" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="orderform-inner">
        <ol class="questions" id="questions">
            <li>
                <span><label for="oName">Please enter your name or the company name</label></span>
                <input class="finput" id="oName" name="oName" type="text" maxlength="20"/>
                <span class="input-error"></span>
            </li>
       </ol>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function _validate(input) {
    if( input.val() === '' ) {
        _showError(input, 'EMPTYSTR');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function _checkForm() {
    $('#orderForm .finput').each(function(){
        $(this).focusout(function() {
            _validate($(this)); 
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    _checkForm()

    $('form#orderForm').submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); // for ajax submission
        if(!_checkForm()) {
            $('button.submit').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            // ajax post
        }
    });
});
```

**Update:** There is no problem with disabling button. The problem is that after correcting errors, again the disabled attribute remains! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add your `HTML` also? Code seems fine to me. Are you getting any error in console??

Comment: yeah, add html.Let's me see what going on

Comment: added the html section and also updated my problem

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a result from the `_checkForm(){}` function. You do from the `_validate` one, and pass it to it, but you don't use/pass the result from `_checkForm()`, therefore this validation:

```
if(!_checkForm()) {...}
```

is always true, because `_checkForm` returns nothing(undefined) and your `!`-ing it. Also, if the check passes, you should `return false` to break the submit.

Comment: You know what the problem is?!! it disables the button, but after correcting the errors it does not remove the disabled attribute

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat well don't disable it then. Just `alert` something. Or if you disable it, just re-enable it, if the `_checkForm` returns `true`

Comment: adding `$('button.submit').prop('disabled', false);` to else condition does not do anything !!!

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat Well of course it doesn't. It's already disabled. That's why you should do it either live, with onkeydown events on the inputs, or call the `_checkForm` some other way

Comment: @AfshinHaghighat Search in google for "javascript validate form live" and you'll see plenty on examples

Answer (score 0):

You forget the return false.

please try this:

```
function _validate(input) {
    if( input.val() === '' ) {
        _showError(input, 'EMPTYSTR');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
function _checkForm() {
    $('#orderForm .finput').each(function(){
        $(this).focusout(function() {
            _validate($(this)); 
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form#orderForm').submit(function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault(); // for ajax submission
        if(!_checkForm()) {
            $('button.submit').prop('disabled', true);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // ajax post
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**test1.html**

```js
function _validate(input) {
  if( input.val() === '' ) {
    _showError(input, 'EMPTYSTR');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function _checkForm() {
  $('#orderForm .finput').each(function(){
    $(this).focusout(function() {
      _validate($(this));
    });
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  _checkForm();

  $('form#orderForm').submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault(); // for ajax submission
    if(!_checkForm()) {
      $('button.submit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
      // ajax post
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="orderForm">

  <input class="finput">

  <button class="submit">submit</button>

</form>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="test1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```